# renaming files with conversion from hex

Tags: command-line, rename

I want to rename the below files, such that the first 4 chars and last 7 chars are removed, the remaining chars to be converted to decimal, while rename.

Example if the filename is `0030002345678.txt`, should be renamed to 00.txt(removing the chars and converting to hex).

If it is `00300A2345678.txt`, should be renamed to 10.txt(after conversion from hex of '0A'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

`ls | python -c 'import sys, os; print len([os.system("mv %s %02i.%s" % (name[:-1], int(name.split(".")[0][4:-7], 16), name.split(".")[1])) for name in sys.stdin])'`

Assumes the files to be renamed are exactly those that `ls` would print; supply anything more relevant, if this is not the case.